# Using a sub-view when sending mail from Laravel 4

Tags: email, laravel, subview, laravel-4

Is there any way to use a nested view when sending mail from Laravel 4?

You send mail like this:

```
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($m)
{
    $m->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

And you create a sub-view like this:

```
$view = View::make('greeting')->nest('child', 'child.view', $data);
```

So you'd think you could just pass a view into the send mail method like this:

```
$view = View::make('emails.welcome')->nest('child', 'child.view', $data);
Mail::send($view, $data, function($m)
{
    $m->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

But from looking at the mail class it seems that the first parameter for the send method needs to be a string and that it composes the view for you based on that. Can anyone think of a way around this issue?

Comment: Have never tried it, but you should be able to. So long as you return it to the email's body...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about passing the child view through as data to the main view?  That's pretty much what `nest()` does for you...

```
$child = View::make('child.view', $data);
$data['child'] = $child;
Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($m) use ($user)
{
    $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Welcome!');
});
```